# Loop through all my worksheets VBA with For Each

Tags: vba, excel

Why this macro doesn't change the color of all my worksheets?
It only works for the first worksheet of my active workbook.
I want it to go through all my worksheets of my workbook.
thanx

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CheckBox13_Click()
    Dim I As Long, j As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If CheckBox13.Value = True Then
            For I = 1 To 700
                For j = 1 To 10
                    If Cells(I, j).Interior.Color = RGB(252, 252, 250) Then
                        Cells(I, j).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
                    End If
                Next j
            Next I
        End If

        If CheckBox13.Value = False Then
            For I = 1 To 700
                For j = 1 To 10
                    If Cells(I, j).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217) Then
                        Cells(I, j).Interior.Color = RGB(252, 252, 250)
                    End If
                Next j
            Next I
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Add ws in front of all your Cells statements. `ws.Cells(I, j).Interior.Color = ...` unless you specify the worksheet you want it will default to the active one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you use `Cells(I, j)` that refers to the active worksheet. You will want to use the `ws` object in your reference like this:

```
ws.Cells(I, j)
```

Comment: For additional information read [VBA Best Practices: Never assume the worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/9218/never-assume-the-worksheet).